# one-hot encoding only categorical features on dataframe with mixed types

Tags: python, dataframe, sparse-matrix, categorical-data, dummy-variable

I have a dataframe with categorical features and numeric features. I want to one-hot encode only the categorical features but when I do get_dummies it returns an error. I need to use sparse because I have a lot of data in the categorical features when they are one-hot encoded.

```
notToDummy = [num1,num2,num3,num4....]
toDummy = [cat1,cat2,cat3,cat4....]
X_dummies = pd.get_dummies(X,columns = toDummy, sparse=True)
X_dummies = X_dummies.sparse.to_coo().tocsr()


>>AttributeError: Can only use the '.sparse' accessor with Sparse data.
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: From what I understand in the doc. Sparse is used when you have a lot of **similar/equal**  values that you don't want to store in memory. Is it your case ?

Comment: my dataframe would fill up too much memory if just plain onehot encoded so I have to use sparse